# Interaction between 2 classloaders

Tags: java, classloader

Say, I have two classloaders in same JVM, CL1 & CL2.

CL1 loads class A & CL2 loads class B

Now, A wants to access B. But I don't want to load B again in CL1. Is it possible for A(loaded in CL1) to access B(loaded in CL2)?

Comment: did you try making CL2 parent class loader of CL1?

Comment: You can use B.class.[getClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()), which gives the classloader of the class you want..

Comment: Thanks Rohit. That helps. Any other way to achieve it?

Comment: can you access CL2? CL2.load(B) ?

Answer (score 2):

If CL2 is parent of CL1 then no problem. If Cl2 and Cl1 are somehow connected OSGi-like, then also they can know each other. IF you write Cl2 and/or CL1 yourself then you can setup such a link. Otherwise, they cannot "know" each other except using reflection or a common interface loaded above CL1 and CL2.

Comment: So, simply put, you can use it only if the class loaders are on the same hierarchy branch. Am I understanding it correctly ? Is the order important - I mean, CL2 MUST be a parent of CL1?